# cant put two divs in one line without messing up container's height

Tags: css, html, height

I'm trying to put 2 divs in one row but when i manage to do that - main container's HEIGHT is not adjusted correctly:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="info">Text</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button value="Accept">Accept</button>
        <button value="Decline">Decline</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
border:1px solid #800000;

margin: 8px;
height:auto;
}

.info{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}

.controls{
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
width: 130px;
padding: 8px;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
background-color: #D4D0C8;
float: right;
}

button{
width:100%; // what ever you want it to be
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76Raj/33/)

how do I fix the container height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with float-based layouts: the container does not stretch to accomodate the height of its floated children. There are two simple solutions to this problem:

- Adding a div to `clear:both` (as AliRiza recommends in another answer).
- Adding `overflow:auto` to the container.

I would advocate for using the latter method because it does not involve adding an HTML element just for the sake of presentation. [See more info on this here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

It can be implemented like this:

```
.container {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/76Raj/35/)

Comment: yes, it works. Just one more question - how do I set "width: 100%;" of "info" div correctly? when i do so - divs stop being on the same line

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to set `.info` to have `width:100%`?

Comment: yes, .info {width: 100%; } and at the same time .controls {width: 130px;}

Comment: `width:100%` means that the width of `.info` will be equal to the entire width of the container. That means that `.controls` has to move to the next line. What is your reason for using `width:100%`? I'm sure there is a more efficient way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` at the end of container div

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="info">Text</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button value="Accept">Accept</button>
        <button value="Decline">Decline</button>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

edited [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alirizaadiyahsi_44/76Raj/34/)

Answer (score 0):

css

```
<style>
div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid #ccc;
vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
```

html

```
<div>your div 1</div>
<div>Your div 2</div>
```

The vertical align is to keep it at the top if u add different amount of text and images as it goes down lol